# Why does extending a generic break this conditional type?

Tags: typescript

Consider this function with a simple conditional type on the second argument:

```
function isFoxy<T>(x: T, flag: T extends object ? string : number) {
    console.log(`hmm, not sure`, x, flag)
}
```

It behaves as expected, distinguishing `object` arguments from non-`object` ones:

```
type Fox = { fox: string }
const fox: Fox = { fox: 'mulder' }

// everything is fine here
isFoxy(fox, 'yes')
isFoxy('cow', 10)
// @ts-expect-error
isFoxy(fox, 10)
// @ts-expect-error
isFoxy('cow', 'yes')
```

But now I want to call it from inside a scope where I know a particular value extends from `object`:

```
function foxify<F extends Fox>(fox: F) {
    isFoxy(fox, 'yes')  // ❌ type inference broken :(
}
```

Type inference is now broken and the function won't compile; it complains that `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'F extends object ? string : number'`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgMTgDwJ4B4AqAfABSYBci+ANIsADYCGA5hfogKaZTtgAmKiOACMAVu2iIA-IhRQATjDBNEFMCAC2Q9nICUiAN4AoRCcQQEKOHXYA6OnCbEABqmRRaWbJKc1MNesw6hgC+hoZQ2AAO7IgYmIgAvAYe5DLyisqh5mCygiBQKDC87HEUcYkGwFgUAOTqIHTFcjWhhgD0bRwAbtrYUAAWGcgCwIox-drshqhx2MRw+YXFcTQ12OwoNUEznsQ15gDuNTQAjAAMQR2IAAIFALSc0dAPcnJwctPouwsFRSVYpwu7U6txQD0wTygLzeHx2OD2h2OiDWGy2YVAkFgCBSMGAeDQHC4PH4sSwJEUS3+qTQeiMpkQVxsTMQQnyyDAwEmkBiQjk7AYAGsBBM+TR2D0kAMFkx+ohjKYrgT6rktIgGKT4gw+IgBpMqny1UhhGJoPKTHC5hS-itketNkFgkA)

Why can't TypeScript infer this type correctly when fox is an `F extends Fox` instead of just a `Fox`? How can I fix the problem?

Comment: TypeScript really doesn't do much analysis of generic conditional types; they mostly stay unevaluated and thus the compiler doesn't know what specific values might be assignable to them.  There's a feature request at [ms/TS#23132](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23132) to improve that, but it's not part of the language. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Seems like you've identified the issue. I'd love to hear more about how to avoid it, or failing that, work around it (hopefully keeping as much hackiness as possible inside `isFoxy` rather than at the call sites).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't really try to evaluate [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depend on [generic type parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  It mostly leaves them as opaque/deferred types and therefore cannot verify that any specific type is assignable to it.  Even if the type parameter is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), that constraint isn't used to try to evaluate the conditional type.  There's a longstanding feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#23132](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23132) to support using generic constraints to evaluate conditional types, but so far it's not part of the language.

Inside the body of `foxify()`, the call to `isFoxy` requires its second argument be of the generic conditional type `F extends object ? string : number`.  But since the compiler doesn't try to evaluate that in light of the `object` constraint on `F`, it doesn't know that the `string` `"yes"` is assignable to it.

The workaround here is probably to widen your generic-typed value to a specific one like this:

```
function foxify<F extends Fox>(insideFox: F) {
    // widen with a different variable
    const widenedInsideFox: object = insideFox;
    isFoxy(widenedInsideFox, "yes"); // okay

    // or widen by manually specifying the type argument to isFoxy
    isFoxy<object>(insideFox, "yes"); // okay
}
```

Or, in the worst case, use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and move on:

```
isFoxy(insideFox, 'yes' as F extends object ? string : number);
```

Still, since you mentioned trying to fix it by changing `isFoxy()`, you could try to replace its single generic conditional call signature with a pair of [overloaded call signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```
type Primitive = string | number | bigint | boolean | symbol | null | undefined;

function isFoxy(x: object, flag: string): void;
function isFoxy(x: Primitive, flag: number): void;
function isFoxy(x: unknown, flag: string | number) {
    console.log(`is it foxy?`, x, flag)
}
```

Now there's no issue with generic conditional types because there's no conditional type at all.  The compiler is happy with

```
function foxify<F extends Fox>(insideFox: F) {
    isFoxy(insideFox, 'yes'); // okay
}
```

because the `isFoxy` call matches the first call signature.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB1AlgEwsNwDmSA3gFBJlIBmArsPAC5oD2wSaUAYowB4CeAPABUAfAAouALiQCANJQA2IPJIFIIXOtgxQkjAEYArCPSQB+JFDoAnXAUnAqYXREsBKIqXKf4zKIzkQAOjlGPBEAAzZWOkpuHhMw2S5ZCgU8Fw8yAF9iDKQ6HhhkTi4kAF4iGIlzKxskbK8faMYqOihMCGLJYrKKim5JAHIwKjksSwG6nM8AemnVADdnHjoAC1rIilxkFecIXLZinhFm1vbi2QGeaAH0zwPYkQHvAHcB2QBGAAZb8lmkAAFWgBaNSFeggyyWRiWfYcB4nNpYc5IL4-Mh-QFQEFcMF0CFQmF3OG8R4vN5IS7XdK5ai0BjMSpoCj8diqdSabTFUS4REdfpIdhuEi5ImHPh6Qz0bnAXnIgBEVygcpcAG4pp5yN4ZdFnu1gBAMABJGVnfkSozRco801cNUa8j3Em6rD6o0mpHcWQK6DKlVIP6MADWIB46vtjqO1o9SQpiomIE5bI0wC0OgMFtM1Ws+CQdgcTlcdvI2WyoEgsAQRTQJWFnnyhSQAAVrGA0AxFj0LNmCAAfJD2RzOJB93RoPC4aIjxh+CAgFh9qA8Rx+Yf9kZyVc0LCbV1qmk0ehMFgRsSSc30ZKpSRdmwuSTzRiYItkWmHhknqrNtCt9sQS+KPNB1ce9HwwZ9KAPelj2JI4qhoQNgEYZ5gH-JQs1qPsBwLIURU1HwZyCEJwkiNtKjiBIkBjFJFDRSZcnrIpuB6QhKmvGoc3qPDtR0FpZX5bpyhYvoqiGEYxgmbJcj+CBFksZY1hzDYtiQHZLD2UV4V4m0LjjWiTyeJDyVRKS5kxbFcXxaFYUOY4tOjD5vhMgFgVBC1LMJB0YNJQydKpMMILpI9GWZPhWTUZNUy5EQoz5KpBXce0yBPGLkUpKAblyEsgA)